# Passing variables from header.php to template and vice verca

Tags: variables, globals

I've defined a variable - let's call it `$header_var`, which is placed in the header.php file. I would like this variable to be passed onto my template file (in this case taxonomy.php).

Also I would like to be able to do the same the other way around, like passing a `$template_var` from my taxonomy.php to header.php.

Is this even possible since the variable was not declared once the header was loaded?

I've tried using global `$header_var` but without luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30):

> I've defined a variable - let's call it
>   $header_var, which is placed in the header.php file. I would like this
>   variable to be passed onto my template file (in this case
>   taxonomy.php).

`global` is not a very recommended way to do the trick, but it works if you use it properly: put it before to define the variable in `header.php` **and again** before retrieve the variable in `taxonomy.php` (after having called get_header() to include `header.php`)

```
// in header.php
global $header_var;
$header_var = 'A value';

// in taxonomy.php
get_header();
global $header_var;
echo $header_var; // 'A value'
```

> I would like to be able to do the same the other way around, like
>   passing a $template_var from my taxonomy.php to header.php. Is this
>   even possible since the variable was not declared once the header was
>   loaded?

It's PHP, not magic nor time machine: time rules apply to WordPress like to [the rest of the universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_physics).

So, no, you can't pass a variable back in time, but usually, in templates, you include `header.php` by calling `get_header()` so if you set a variable **before** calling that function, the global *trick* will work too:

```
// in header.php
global $template_var;
echo $template_var; // 'A value'

// in taxonomy.php
global $template_var;
$template_var = 'A value'
get_header();
```

However if you need to share variables in `header.php` and templates, best thing to do is do not declare them in header nor in templates, but in `functions.php` using [action hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to control *when* variables have to be declared.

An useful hook to is `'template_redirect'` where you have access to current query and it is fired before `header.php` and templates are loaded.

A rough example:

```
// in functions.php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'get_my_shared_vars' );

function get_my_shared_vars() {
   static $shared_vars = NULL;
   if ( empty( $shared_vars ) ) {
     $shared_vars = array( 'header_var' => 'An header value' );
     if ( is_tax() || is_category() || is_tag() ) {
       $shared_vars['taxonomy_var'] = 'A taxonomy value';
     }
   }
   return $shared_vars;
}


// in header.php
$shared_vars = get_my_shared_vars();
echo $shared_vars['header_var']; // 'An header value'

// in taxonomy.php
$shared_vars = get_my_shared_vars();
echo $shared_vars['taxonomy_var']; // 'A taxonomy value'
```

In previous code, thanks to `static` keyword all the code in `get_my_shared_vars` function used to set variables runs only once, so you don't have to worry about performance issues if calling the function more than once.

Comment: If I could I would vote 1000. This should be in WP template docs

Comment: It's need to declare global in the other file I declare it on in `header.php` and call the variable directly.

Answer (score 6):

### Wordpress 5.5+

Since 5.5.0 `get_header` has `$args` parameter

[get_header changelog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/#changelog)

```
get_header( 'foo', [ 'header_var' => 'A value' ] ); // header-foo.php will be loaded

/**
 * OR
 */

get_header( null, [ 'header_var' => 'A value' ] ); // header.php will be loaded
```

**header.php**

```
<?php echo $args['header_var']; ?>

/**
 * OR
 */

<?php extract($args); ?>
<?php echo $header_var; ?>

/**
 * Or with defaults
 */

$defaults = array( 
    'header_var2' => 'bar',
    // ...
);
extract(wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ));

<?= $header_var ?>
<?= $header_var2 ?>
```

Comment: This is a much better approach and viser than using a global variable. There are some articles out there regarding using a global variable in PHP. Here is one: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/essential-php-security/059600656X/ch01.html