# Set Title from Custom Template

Tags: customization, templates, title, api

I'm building a site that uses a custom template to display a set of listings that are pulled from an external API. I need to set the title and meta description values using data from the API.

I've found plenty of examples using functions.php and seo hooks but I need to avoid making a second call to the api when functions.php is called and would prefer to set the title and meta description during my initial api call.

Comment: On what hook is the API called? Please show your code. Otherwise, this question is too broad.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by passing a global variable before get_header() was called in my template. I used the following post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149333/passing-variables-from-header-php-to-template-and-vice-verca

Comment: Glad to hear! Please post your solution as an answer to this question, then come back in a couple of days and accept it so that it's closed out.

Comment: Also had to get title from API and only think that worked for me was getting the head and replacing from it - see here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269862/how-to-set-custom-title-of-custom-page-template/338510#338510

Answer (score 0):

Use global variables to pass values from the template to the header.

```
// in the template file  

global $my_page_title;  
$my_page_title = 'field value';  

global $my_meta_description;  
$my_meta_description = 'field value';  

get_header();  

// in the header file  
global $my_page_title;  
global $my_meta_description;  

echo $my_page_title;  
echo $my_meta_description;
```