# How to create dynamic templates?

Tags: php, templates

So let's say that I have a navbar template with the following content:

// template_parts / navbar.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg dark bg-transparent fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
     This is the company name
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there a way to pass a variable to the template in order to change, in this case, the company's name when calling the template?

Something like `get_template_part("template_parts/navbar","Microsoft");`

I know the above syntax works for another purpose, I'm just trying to illustrate what I want to achieve.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing variables from header.php to template and vice verca](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149333/passing-variables-from-header-php-to-template-and-vice-verca)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the template like this `include(locate_template('template-part.php'));`. to pass the variable or used the outer variable/ dynamic values in the template.